# Choice architecture docker for continious integration using docker

Tags: jenkins, docker, continuous-integration

I want to move my contininous integration tool in containers dockers. 
Which architecture is more interessent beetween :

1. Having a image of a OS like centos and install in all my tools (jenkins, sonarqube, ...) OR 
2. Have a container foreach tool (jenkins, sonarqube, gitlab, ...) ?

My integration tools are stable and there is not much movement.

In the picture atached, I designed a stack of each architecture. 
Which architecture is the best and why ? What are the pro and cons of each one.

[Stack of these 2 architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2k3W.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003338/docker-one-process-per-container) and [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#/run-only-one-process-per-container) it's recommended to use multiple containers.

PRO:

- Easier to debug (when it's al in one image it's difficult to see the specific logs because all the logs are mixed)
- When there is going something wrong there is not an impact on every process
- You're able to divide multiple containers over multiple servers and use orchestration tools. (you can create one container for every jenkins-slave).
- Rolling upgrades (when you want to go to a newer version of jenkins you don't have to rebuild/redeploy your whole environment which is in one image).
- Don’t create large images. A large image will be harder to distribute

CON:

- Communication between multiple containers. Your communication between Jenkins, Sonarqube etc. will be easier
  when it's al in one container.
- multiple container are probably more difficult to setup